# Метод open помечается "unexpected token"

Tags: python

Окружение: Python 3.9.0, visual studio.

Цель: выгрузить и сохранить html страницы.

Изучаю парсинг и с самого начала возникла проблема, а именно:

```
import requests
import os

url = 'https://eda.ru/recepty'
r = requests.get(url)
#open unexpected token
with open('H:\\ProgramProject\\WebParsingEda.ru\\SaveResult\\test.html', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text.encode('cp1251'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как это исправить.

Comment: Из текста вопроса не понятно, что именно вы делаете с данным кодом, какой вид парсинга изучаете и какой результат хотите получить. Так же укажите версию интерпритатора. В строке `output_file.write(r.text.encode('cp12 51'))` название кодировки написано неверно. Правильно : `"cp1251"`

Comment: А какая у вас версия Питона, для начала?

Comment: И кодировку надо в `open` указывать параметром `encoding='cp1251'`, а так как вы хотите сделать всё-равно не получится, будет ругаться, что строку не умеет энкодить, только байты.

Comment: @cauf добавил цель и версию интерпретатора

Comment: @Дмитри В Google Colab нормально ваш код интерпретируется, что-то у вас не совпадает в показаниях. Вы в какой среде смотрите эти ошибки которые на скриншоте? Может среда другую версию питона подхватывает, а не ту, которую вы хотели.

Comment: @CrazuElf Использую M Visual Studio. Среда используется точно 3.9.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2210 это проблема с Парсером python на vs  посмотрите здесь поднимали уже эту тему

Comment: @Riangry обновил ide проблема решилась, спасибо.

Comment: @CrazyElf можешь показать пример как нужно вписать кодировку, а то проблему решил и начала ругаться на то о чем ты сообщил

Comment: @Дмитри По той ссылке выше на гитхаб там же как-раз приведён пример как в open прописать encoding, там только сама кодировка другая, а так прямо готовый для вас пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано [@Riangry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/401877/riangry) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205417/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-open-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-unexpected-token?noredirect=1#comment2104995_1205417) - решение можно найти [по этой ссылке](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2210)

В коде так же были ошибки по работе с файлами. Корректный вариант будет таким:

```py
import requests
import os

url = 'https://eda.ru/recepty'
r = requests.get(url)
#open unexpected token
with open(r'C:\Users\af.gorbunov\Work\temp.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Только автору вроде cp1251 кодировка нужна

Comment: Не нужна, а он ее указал. Зачем-то. Судя по всему, пытался избавиться от кракозябр. Контент на страницах в интернете в utf-8. Зачем нужно перекодировать в cp1251 - для меня большой секрет

Comment: А может ему потом в Экселе файл открывать ))

Comment: С рецептами. Вообще-то ексель прекрасно прочтет utf-8